# How do I find out how LogisticRegression in sklearn classified my test data?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a simple LogisticRegression model that I am using to classify some training data as below:

```
clf = LogisticRegression()
training_output = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Once the model is trained I am using some test data to evaluate its performance:

```
score = clf.score(x_test, y_test)
```

So far so good. I am able to get the score and create confusion matrix.

But, is there a way for me to get how the model classified the x_test , so I can compare if against y_test row by row?

Answer (score 0):

Please explain your question more. If you want to have the prediction of the model you can just use the [predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict) method:

```
test_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

If you want to know *how* the decision was made, have a look at the `coef_` attribute and see what is the influence of each variable (It is better to scale the input data before interpreting the coefficients)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly,  you can use the `predict` function,
here is the signature :

`predict(X)`
where X is you matrix of training Data.
Returns
`y_predndarray` of shape (n_samples,)
Vector containing the class labels for each sample.